# Best Way to (truly) Reduce Gradient Banding in Photoshop across ALL Monitors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, gradient

This problem keeps coming up again and again. I have tried to use the Dither checkbox in a Layer Effect in Photoshop CS6+ but that doesnt always work so well.

And applying a grain effect or noise effect just looks horrible sometimes.

It might be that I am not doing this correctly so would love feedback or leads to online tutorials that really solve this issue.

NOTE: I am preparing graphics strictly for web — so need to make gradients smooth in all displays including Apple Thunderbolt Displays, iPhone, iPad and even crappy monitors with low color gamuts.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do *anything* for **all** monitors. There's no way to adjust for pixel density, calibration, etc. within the image itself. You're sort of asking for the impossible here.

Comment: Have you seen these two questions?: [**Is it really impossible to have gradient without banding?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/is-it-really-impossible-to-have-gradient-without-banding) and [**How do you avoid bands of prominent color in gradients?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16246/how-do-you-avoid-bands-of-prominent-color-in-gradients)

Answer (score 1):

I use Motion Blur to help reduce Gradient Banding, but this will only help with linear gradients.