# Striped gradient after saving vector in Adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, gradient, jpg, anti-aliasing

After saving an **.ai** to **.jpg** I've got striped lines on gradient background.

Anti aliases is enabled.

How can I get smooth transition in this case?

[image]

Comment: I would also check out this question [Is it really impossible to have a gradient without banding](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/is-it-really-impossible-to-have-gradient-without-banding)

Answer (score 2):

You should save it as a `.png` if you want to retain quality.

JPEG does a horrible job compressing images, which is what you're seeing

---

I just made a little rectangle with a gradient and exported one as `.jpg` one as `.png` (without any optimization settings)

Compare my JPEG:

[image]

With my PNG:

[image]